# what is the meaning of "co-indexed" in English?

Tags: american-english, british-english

I know that English people use "co-" prefix to show something is "joint" or "jointly Verb" with something else . But I encountered a key sentence in a article and I cannot understand it well:

> "we use this classification method to represent images' attributes,
>   and **co-indexed** images into a new file according to their
>   characteristics"

what the "co-indexed" means in this sentence? 
An image is jointly indexed with what? I think it should be something like this

> **X** is co-indexed with **Y**

does it mean that every pair of images is jointly indexed?

The phrase is not a technical one.

Comment: Do you have any more information that would shed light on the actual indexing scheme that was used to "co-index" the images?  What characteristics were used, and how was the index organized?  This might shed some light on the choice of "co-indexed" over "indexed."

Comment: One assumes it simply means they "ordered" the pictures according to their attributes, only "co-" implies that the "ordering" was done without affecting the primary order of the images.  Eg, in a physical implementation separate index cards in a card file might be used to represent the image attributes.  And on a computer it is, of course, much simpler -- just build an index over a "secondary key" of the computer database.

Comment: (The terminology for this, even among computer database geeks, is not well-established.  It's not unusual to have to flail about for a suitable description.)

Answer (score 1):

Co-Indexed seems to mean to Index (or sort) together

So when they stated

> "co-indexed images into a new file according to their characteristics"

it just means their sorting the images into the file based on characteristics